# Unable to create a column which can store character as part of DMS task to replicate to postgres DB(Target)

Tags: postgresql, types, transformation, dms

I am trying to setup a DMS task to load data from SQL Server to Postgres and as part of the task I have an additional column which I wanted to add  as Server name (I will be hardcoding the value for this column).

But in the transformation rule if I mention the column data type as String and if I specify the column value as  a character, the task will fail. At the same time instead of Character if  mention the column value as a numeric value task will replicate.

Thanks,

Comment: Please show your code and what you have already tried. [ask]

Comment: For large strings, you would use a `text` column in Postgres